# Browser sometimes displays JSON text instead of desired page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

I have been experiencing an intermittent issue in my Rails app, and I'm having trouble figuring out what is going on.  When the user logs in, they see a dashboard that contains some JavaScript code which performs an AJAX call to an action.  Occasionally, instead of seeing the dashboard, when the user logs in, they see the JSON response text from the action instead of the dashboard (in Chrome) or they download a .json file (Firefox).  It's intermittent and doesn't usually happen, but it's really annoying when it does occur.

Here's a dumbed down version of some of the code:

JS running in the template head:

```
$(function () {
    var remoteLink = $('#remoteLink');
    remoteLink.live("ajax:complete", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
           loadCount();
        }, 30000);
    });    

    loadCount();

    function loadCount() {
      remoteLink.click();
    }
});
```

And the link in the template:

```
<%= link_to 'get count (hidden)', {:controller => 'something', :action => 'count'}, 
            :id => 'remoteLink', :class => 'hidden', :remote => true, 'data-type' => 'json' %>
```

And the controller action:

```
def count
    render :json => get_counts_function_returning_a_hash
end
```

My hunch is that it's a race condition -- perhaps related to the use of setTimeout? -- but I haven't been able to verify that hunch.  Can anyone tell me what might be going on here?  I've seen this in the wild on other sites, too -- also intermittent, not generally occurring but annoying when it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have any authentication code that uses store_location or similar functionality to redirect the user to a specific page after they have logged in?

I once had a similar problem where the AJAX callback was causing store_location to store the JSON URL and the user was redirected to the JSON response rather than their dashboard. This was hard to track down because the user had to sit idle at the page for some time before the bug was manifest.

In any case, I suspect it is something like this rather than a problem with Rails.

Comment: Oh, very interesting. We're not using store_location specifically, but we have our own implementation of something similar. I will investigate and accept this answer if that's what is going on.

Comment: You win! That was my problem. I was recording the AJAX request URL and forwarding the user to it after login.  If the user was logged out while the JS was still polling the server, AND the user returned to the login page without clicking on any other links in the app, this problem would occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the Content-Type of the HTTP response and check any places you are setting it for possible bugs. Run your browser with an extension for tracing HTTP headers to capture what the values are when it does occur.

Comment: Well, as far as I can observe, it seems to be set correctly (application/json).  I am not setting it manually anywhere -- I think render :json should take care of that -- and I see Content-Type: application/json in Firebug and Chrome dev tools.  When I get 304 Not Modified, however, there is no Content-Type header.  That seems fine to me, though, since I believe a 304 should not have any text in the body.  What I actually see, however, is a 304 that still contains the JSON body.  Perhaps including this non-empty body in the 304 response is causing a problem in certain situations?