# JSON ajax response outputed to screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

Our server is located in europe. 
Now and then an american based user reports a problem when he uses the `$.getJSON` function.

His browser just displays the json response instead of catching it and passing it to javascript.

The ajax call just looks like:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json_data){ ... });
```

Any ideas?

More info:

1. The the same user has the problem in FF and IE.
2. I use Ruby On Rails `render :json`. which response type is `application/json`.

Comment: Hi, Tom. Can you post some code?

Comment: $.getJSON(url, function(json_data){ ... }).

Comment: We have a lot of users and none of them have ever reported such a problem. So I'm guessing that the code works. Maybe it has to do with latency, timeouts...

Comment: What the browser does the user use?

Comment: What response type is your server putting out? (`application/json`, or...?) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type

Comment: The the same user has the problem in FF and IE

Comment: I use Ruby On Rails render :json. which response type is 'application/json'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643570/browser-sometimes-displays-json-text-instead-of-desired-page

Answer (score 2):

Try using the $.ajax() method so you can handle errors and debug the success callback.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        url: url,
        success: function(json_data) {
            // parse json_data object
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // check for errors                
        } 
    });
```

Aside from that using an XHR viewer like Firebug or Chrome's built-in utility (CTRL+SHIFT+I) can be very helpful.

XHR DOM reference: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_http.asp